# HOW to make field mandatory depending on another field value in XSD

Tags: xsd

I have this xsd element- I want to restrict it to if in another field in the message - Invoice Type - i have the value Credit - the tag Matching_Credited_Invoice_Number must contain text and cannot be NULL.

```
<xs:element name="Matching_Credited_Invoice_Number">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,10}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: That requirement "must contain text" doesn't make much sense to me for an element whose type has been set to contain only ASCII digits. Unless you consider ASCII digits to be "text". A possible NULL in XSD would usually represented by ` nillable="true"`` on the `xs:element`, you haven't used that so the value can not be set to `xsi:nil="true"` anyway. Are you using XSD 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: Hi , First thanks :) I'm using XSD 1.0 and I need to when the field - Invoice_Type has the value -"Credit" , the field Matching_Credited_Invoice_Number must contain some value- you right - numeric values and if the type is different - the field can stay empty from values

Comment: I need to know how to do it using some condition I guess

Comment: XSD 1.1 has assertions to express such conditions.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in 1.1?

Comment: To put an assertion into the right context, we would really need to see that context in your schema, i.e. the declaration and position of that other element you want to refer to in the condition.

Comment: How can I share it with you? Both elements under parent element <Header>

Comment: By editing your question and showing the details of the schema there, like you have already shown the declaration for the one element. Show us the context as well.

Comment: If you want to work it out on your own, read the section about assertions in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions or perhaps first in an introduction to the new features in XSD 1.1. like given in https://www.altova.com/blog/what-s-new-in-xml-schema-11/.  Type alternative might also be an option https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative if the other value can be given in an attribute instead of an element.